# Displaying each element in an array in sequence

Tags: arrays, swift, delay, display

I am trying to display each member of a text array for several seconds. The code I wrote displays the last member for the entire time. How should this be fixed?

```swift
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var connectedView: UIView?
    var emotionView: UIView?
    var labelsButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
              
    let labels = ["Apple", "Baby", "Cat", "Dog", "Evening", "Friend", "Go", "Happy", "Independent", "Joyful"]
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        layoutForConnected()
    }
  
    @objc func didTouchlabelButton(_ sender: UIButton?) {
        sender?.setTitle("Labels", for: .normal)
        layoutForCharacter()
    }
          
    func layoutForConnected() {
        if connectedView == nil {
            connectedView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
            connectedView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            
            labelsButton.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 475, width: 180, height: 60)
            labelsButton.setTitle("Labels", for: .normal)
            labelsButton.addTarget(self,action:
                                        #selector(didTouchlabelButton),for: .touchUpInside)
            labelsButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
            labelsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hue: 0.563, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0.93, alpha: 1.0)
            labelsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            connectedView?.addSubview(labelsButton)
        }
        
        if let connectedView = connectedView {
            self.view.addSubview(connectedView)
        }
    }
    
    var displayTime = 5.0
    var index = 0
       
    func layoutForCharacter() {
                
        // set up frame and background color
        emotionView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        emotionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hue: 0.563, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0.93, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let labelLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 400 , width: view.frame.size.width, height: 20))
        labelLabel.textAlignment = .center
        
        // Display each label for displayTime seconds
               index = 0
        
        view?.addSubview(labelLabel)
        labelLabel.text = labels[index]
        
        while index < 9
        {
          labelLabel.text = labels[index] // Displays "Joyful", i.e. index = 9
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + displayTime * Double(index))
            {  [self] in
                labelLabel.text = labels[index]
            }
            self.index += 1
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + displayTime * Double(index))
        {  [self] in
            self.layoutForConnected()
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the location of `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` but this has not corrected the problem.

Comment: Unrelated but why are you importing `SwiftUI` instead of `UIKit`?

Comment: The main problem is that you are calling `labelLabel.text = labels[index]` twice inside the `while` loop. Remove the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite it in a recursive way. It's easy to read.

```swift
func layoutForCharacter() {
    ...
    recursiveShowUpEmotion(label: labelLabel, index: index)
}

private func recursiveShowUpEmotion(label: UILabel, index: Int) {
    guard index < 9 else {
        layoutForConnected()
        return
    }
    label.text = labels[index]
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + displayTime) {
        self.recursiveShowUpEmotion(label: label, index: index + 1)
    }
}
```

And in your scenario, you delayed the label.text assignment, not the index. So when the loop executes, `index` will reach 9 right away. Then 10 times inside `DispatchQueue` at index 9. That's why you always see `Joyful`.

Comment: There's no reason for `index` to be a property. Make it a parameter to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I was not able to get the recursive approach proposed to work, but that may be how I applied it.

With a lot of help from Foti Dim, I developed the following:

```swift
var displayTime = 5.0
var chosenLabel = 0

func layoutForCharacter() {
    // set up frame and background color
    emotionView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
    emotionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hue: 0.563, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0.93, alpha: 1.0)
    
    let labelLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 400 , width: view.frame.size.width, height: 20))
    labelLabel.textAlignment = .center
    
    // Display each label for displayTime seconds
    chosenLabel = 0
    
    view?.addSubview(labelLabel)
    
    // Use a timer to display each label
    var chosenLabel = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: displayTime, repeats: true) { [self] timer in
        // labelLabel.text = String (chosenLabel)
        labelLabel.text = self.labels[chosenLabel]
        
        chosenLabel += 1
        if chosenLabel == self.labels.count {
            timer.invalidate()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.displayTime) {
                self.layoutForConnected()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like your original code, you keep adding a new label on every call to `layoutForCharacter`.